# If $\gcd (a,b,c)=1$ then $\text{lcm}[a,b,c]=abc$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Prove or disprove with counterexample: if  $\text{gcd}(a,b,c)=1\qquad a,b,c\in \mathbb N$
>
> Then $\text{lcm}[a,b,c]=a\cdot b\cdot c$?

---

I believe that the answer is **Yes** because $\text{lcm}[a,b,c]=\frac{abc}{\gcd(a,b,c)}$ , But I am not so sure, am I correct?

Comment: $\gcd(2,3,6)=1$, what's the lowest common multiple? Not $36$, it seems.

Comment: @egreg You are right, thank you

Comment: if $(a,b)=1 gcd$(a,a,b)=? and $a^2b$?

Comment: The property $a\times b= \text{lcm}(a,b) \times \text{gcd}(a,b) $

is only applicable to two numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try with $\gcd(2,3,6)$?

The relation is true if the numbers are *pairwise coprime*.